# YARN SLS - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to do the example of YARN SLS in that folder sls/sample-data. After the configuration of yarn-site.xml and log4j.properties and the copies of sls-runner.xml and fair.schedular.xml from folder sample-conf, I meet many warnings... But I don't know why...
I run the command for example in folder

```
bin/slsrun.sh --input-rumen=sample-data/2jobs2min-rumen-jh.json --output-dir=sample-data
```

My log4j.properties file in etc/hadoop

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
hadoop.root.logger=INFO,console
hadoop.log.dir=.
hadoop.log.file=hadoop.log

# Define the root logger to the system property "hadoop.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${hadoop.root.logger}, EventCounter

# Logging Threshold
log4j.threshold=ALL

# Null Appender
log4j.appender.NullAppender=org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender

#
# Rolling File Appender - cap space usage at 5gb.
#
hadoop.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hadoop.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

log4j.appender.RFA.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFA.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.log.maxbackupindex}

log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
# Debugging Pattern format
#log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


#
# Daily Rolling File Appender
#

log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

# Rollover at midnight
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
# Debugging Pattern format
#log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


#
# console
# Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this
#

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n

#
# TaskLog Appender
#
log4j.appender.TLA=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogAppender

log4j.appender.TLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n

#
# HDFS block state change log from block manager
#
# Uncomment the following to log normal block state change
# messages from BlockManager in NameNode.
#log4j.logger.BlockStateChange=DEBUG

#
#Security appender
#
hadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender
hadoop.security.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hadoop.security.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.category.SecurityLogger=${hadoop.security.logger}
hadoop.security.log.file=SecurityAuth-${user.name}.audit
log4j.appender.RFAS=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFAS.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.security.log.file}
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.security.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.security.log.maxbackupindex}

#
# Daily Rolling Security appender
#
log4j.appender.DRFAS=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFAS.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.security.log.file}
log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
log4j.appender.DRFAS.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

#
# hadoop configuration logging
#

# Uncomment the following line to turn off configuration deprecation warnings.
# log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation=WARN

#
# hdfs audit logging
#
hdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender
hdfs.audit.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hdfs.audit.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=${hdfs.audit.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=false
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/hdfs-audit.log
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.MaxFileSize=${hdfs.audit.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.MaxBackupIndex=${hdfs.audit.log.maxbackupindex}

#
# NameNode metrics logging.
# The default is to retain two namenode-metrics.log files up to 64MB each.
#
namenode.metrics.logger=INFO,NullAppender
log4j.logger.NameNodeMetricsLog=${namenode.metrics.logger}
log4j.additivity.NameNodeMetricsLog=false
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/namenode-metrics.log
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %m%n
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA.MaxFileSize=64MB

#
# DataNode metrics logging.
# The default is to retain two datanode-metrics.log files up to 64MB each.
#
datanode.metrics.logger=INFO,NullAppender
log4j.logger.DataNodeMetricsLog=${datanode.metrics.logger}
log4j.additivity.DataNodeMetricsLog=false
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/datanode-metrics.log
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %m%n
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA.MaxFileSize=64MB

# Custom Logging levels

#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=DEBUG


# AWS SDK & S3A FileSystem
#log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient=ERROR
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem=WARN

#
# Event Counter Appender
# Sends counts of logging messages at different severity levels to Hadoop Metrics.
#
log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter

#
# Job Summary Appender
#
# Use following logger to send summary to separate file defined by
# hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file :
# hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=INFO,JSA
# 
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=${hadoop.root.logger}
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file=hadoop-mapreduce.jobsummary.log
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.appender.JSA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.JSA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file}
log4j.appender.JSA.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.JSA.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxbackupindex}
log4j.appender.JSA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.JSA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=false

#
# shuffle connection log from shuffleHandler
# Uncomment the following line to enable logging of shuffle connections
# log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler.audit=DEBUG

#
# Yarn ResourceManager Application Summary Log
#
# Set the ResourceManager summary log filename
yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.log.file=rm-appsummary.log
# Set the ResourceManager summary log level and appender
yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger=${hadoop.root.logger}
#yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger=INFO,RMSUMMARY

# To enable AppSummaryLogging for the RM,
# set yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger to
# <LEVEL>,RMSUMMARY in hadoop-env.sh

# Appender for ResourceManager Application Summary Log
# Requires the following properties to be set
#    - hadoop.log.dir (Hadoop Log directory)
#    - yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.log.file (resource manager app summary log filename)
#    - yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger (resource manager app summary log level and appender)

log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary=${yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary=false
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.log.file}
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxFileSize=256MB
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n

# HS audit log configs
#mapreduce.hs.audit.logger=INFO,HSAUDIT
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HSAuditLogger=${mapreduce.hs.audit.logger}
#log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HSAuditLogger=false
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/hs-audit.log
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

# Http Server Request Logs
#log4j.logger.http.requests.namenode=INFO,namenoderequestlog
#log4j.appender.namenoderequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.namenoderequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-namenode-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.namenoderequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.datanode=INFO,datanoderequestlog
#log4j.appender.datanoderequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.datanoderequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-datanode-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.datanoderequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.resourcemanager=INFO,resourcemanagerrequestlog
#log4j.appender.resourcemanagerrequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.resourcemanagerrequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-resourcemanager-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.resourcemanagerrequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.jobhistory=INFO,jobhistoryrequestlog
#log4j.appender.jobhistoryrequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.jobhistoryrequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-jobhistory-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.jobhistoryrequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.nodemanager=INFO,nodemanagerrequestlog
#log4j.appender.nodemanagerrequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.nodemanagerrequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-nodemanager-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.nodemanagerrequestlog.RetainDays=3


# WebHdfs request log on datanodes
# Specify -Ddatanode.webhdfs.logger=INFO,HTTPDRFA on datanode startup to
# direct the log to a separate file.
#datanode.webhdfs.logger=INFO,console
#log4j.logger.datanode.webhdfs=${datanode.webhdfs.logger}
#log4j.appender.HTTPDRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.HTTPDRFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/hadoop-datanode-webhdfs.log
#log4j.appender.HTTPDRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.HTTPDRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %m%n
#log4j.appender.HTTPDRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd


# Appender for viewing information for errors and warnings
yarn.ewma.cleanupInterval=300
yarn.ewma.messageAgeLimitSeconds=86400
yarn.ewma.maxUniqueMessages=250
log4j.appender.EWMA=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.Log4jWarningErrorMetricsAppender
log4j.appender.EWMA.cleanupInterval=${yarn.ewma.cleanupInterval}
log4j.appender.EWMA.messageAgeLimitSeconds=${yarn.ewma.messageAgeLimitSeconds}
log4j.appender.EWMA.maxUniqueMessages=${yarn.ewma.maxUniqueMessages}

#
# Fair scheduler state dump
#
# Use following logger to dump the state to a separate file

#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler.statedump=DEBUG,FSSTATEDUMP
#log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler.statedump=false
#log4j.appender.FSSTATEDUMP=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.FSSTATEDUMP.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/fairscheduler-statedump.log
#log4j.appender.FSSTATEDUMP.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.FSSTATEDUMP.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
#log4j.appender.FSSTATEDUMP.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.log.maxfilesize}
#log4j.appender.FSSTATEDUMP.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.log.maxbackupindex}

# Log levels of third-party libraries
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.beanutils=WARN

# Copy from sls
log4j.appender.test=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.test.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.test.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.test.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger=NONE, test
```

My yarn-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<configuration>
  <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
    <!-- <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fifo.FifoScheduler</value> -->
    <!-- <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler</value> -->
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>The address of the RM web application.</description>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>localhost:18088</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>localhost:18031</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>The address of the scheduler interface.</description>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>localhost:18030</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>The address of the applications manager interface in the RM.</description>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>localhost:18032</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>The address of the RM admin interface.</description>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
    <value>localhost:18033</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Set to false, to avoid ip check</description>
    <name>hadoop.security.token.service.use_ip</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications</name>
    <value>1000</value>
    <description>Maximum number of applications in the system which
      can be concurrently active both running and pending</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Whether to use preemption. Note that preemption is experimental
      in the current version. Defaults to false.</description>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <description>Whether to allow multiple container assignments in one
      heartbeat. Defaults to false.</description>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.assignmultiple</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

After my command, its WARNING and other information:

```
2020-02-17 12:48:53,311 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2020-02-17 12:48:53,311 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.xbill.DNS.ResolverConfig (file:/home/host1/usr/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/dnsjava-2.1.7.jar) to method sun.net.dns.ResolverConfiguration.open()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.xbill.DNS.ResolverConfig
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-02-17 12:48:54,010 INFO conf.Configuration: found resource core-site.xml at file:/home/host1/usr/hadoop-3.2.1/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
2020-02-17 12:48:54,279 INFO conf.Configuration: found resource yarn-site.xml at file:/home/host1/usr/hadoop-3.2.1/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml
...
2020-02-17 12:48:58,198 WARN webapp.WebAppContext: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@56da7487{/,file:///tmp/jetty-localhost-18088-cluster-_-any-17039719467842103765.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/cluster}
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver.<init>(JAXBContextResolver.java:41)
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebApp.setup(RMWebApp.java:54)
  while locating org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory$GuiceInstantiatedComponentProvider.getInstance(GuiceComponentProviderFactory.java:345)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:457)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 87 more
2020-02-17 12:48:58,244 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@54e2fe{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:18088}
2020-02-17 12:48:58,244 INFO server.Server: Started @6610ms
...
2020-02-17 12:48:58,294 INFO service.AbstractService: Service ResourceManager failed in state STARTED
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebAppException: Error starting http server
...
...
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 87 more
```

There are too many WARNING and INFO lines after that command...
I don't how to solve it...The other detail is that my Hadoop version is 3.2.1 and my JAVA is 13.
And my reference website is often Hadoop 2 version. I feel fuzzled. 
Please tell me what I should do, Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure. Before it, I run the bin/start-all.sh, it's ok.

Comment: Hadoop requires Java 8